# HSQL access denied loading file

Tags: hsqldb, embedded-database

I've moved from H2 to HSQL as embedded database because h2 doesn't support oracle to_date() function.

But I have another problem with HSQL, I always got an error when I try to use the HSQL load_file() function.
The error is the following:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Access is denied: conf.xml

And my sql query is

```
INSERT INTO "CONFIGURATION" (ID,TIMESTAMP,VALUE,COMMENTS) VALUES ('3TPxB+bO1be+24refPS6IwKSdX7sF1KMtmm1uMkr7rE=',{d '2014-03-13'},LOAD_FILE('conf.xml'),null);
```

conf.xml is in the same directory than the sql script, and it worked with H2.

Could someone point out what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If your database is a file: database, HSQLDB allows loading a file from the directory where the .script and .properties files are located and all its subdirectories.

If your database is a mem: database, you need the system property `textdb.allow_full_path=true` set before you connect to the database. You can do this with  `java -Dtextdb.allow_full_path=true` or by setting the property from your program before opening a connection to the database. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_system_props